# what does it mean for CDF distribution to be unbounded? Example?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

What does it mean for cumulative distribution function (CDF) to be unbounded? What would be an example distribution?

Comment: You should supply some sort of context. What were you studying when you saw "unbounded CDF" mentioned?

Comment: In the definition of a CDF $F(x)$ is that $0\leq F(x)\leq 1$ for all $x$. So it can't be a CDF you are talking about but something different.

Comment: Maybe you mean that the _support_ of the associated distribution is unbounded.